# Converting Mariadb Galera Cluster into Simple Master Slave Replication Cluster

Tags: mysql-replication, mariadb, galera

Now we have this project to convert our Mariadb Galera Cluster (3 nodes) to Simple Master Slave cluster (One master and two slaves). So our goal to get rid of Galera and make our setup just async / semisync Master Slave cluster. We have big tables in our current Galera and it is so annoying with schema changes on these big tables. Schema changes lock the whole cluster so we want to get rid of Galera thing. We will use HAProxy and maybe Maxscale for readwrites split - reads on slaves and writes on master and Failover. Backup will be on Slave 2.

Please if anyone done it before or anyone has info and experience and can write down the steps and main challenges that had to convert your galera setup into simple mariadb.

These are the main steps I have in my mind to do it and read from other question(that question doesn't had any detailed answer and nothing about the challenges):

1- Full backup of data / VMs backup so just in case of restore to the last state in case of failure

2- Stop all Services/APIs connected to the Mariadb Galera cluster

3- Stop mysql services on three nodes

4- check the data directories

5- delete all galera options / galera.cnf on three nodes

6- add Master slave configurations

7- Start the mysql services

8- create slave replication user on master

9-On master node run show master status to get the file bin-log number and position number

10-connect slaves to master by using the change_master_to syntax

11- Test the replication

12- Start APIs

Comment: You did not use RSU for the big Alters?

Comment: @RickJames using RSU can be the solution for schema changes in galera but not totally risk free and what if during desync the node to perform the schema changes we had other nodes desync from cluster and what about at finally end up with two different structures! or maybe with good time scheduling I can do the RSU thing not during the working hours and just when we have few active transactions.

Comment: (This belongs in dba.stackexchange.com, where it might get more traction.)